# Creating RKManagedObjectStore based on Existing Core Data Store

Tags: ios, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I'm not sure if I'm actually understanding what I'm doing but my problem is that I cannot setup the RKManagedObjectStore to use Core Data and RestKit together. I tried the following:

```
NSURL *storeURL = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] containerURLForSecurityApplicationGroupIdentifier:@"group.MYAPPLICATIONURL"];
storeURL = [storeURL URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"MYAPPLICATIONNAME.sqlite"];
NSError *error = nil;
manager.managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:[[CoreDataHandler instance] managedObjectModel]];
[manager.managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:[storeURL absoluteString] fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:nil error:&error];

if (error != nil) {
    NSLog(@"\nSerious object store error: %@", error);
    return;
} else {
    [manager.managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];
}
```

[[CoreDataHandler instance] managedObjectModel] returns the default CoreData object model. I did not change anything concerning the initialisation code provided by the xcode template.

The error I'm getting is:

```
CoreData: error: -addPersistentStoreWithType:SQLite configuration:(null) URL:MYURLTOSQLITEFILE

...

returned error Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=512 "The operation couldn’t be completed. (Cocoa error 512.)" UserInfo=0x7fc5aaf9f290 {reason=Failed to create file; code = 2} with userInfo dictionary {
    reason = "Failed to create file; code = 2";
}
```

So my question is: Am I even trying this the right way? Does RestKit need it's own persistent storage which will be synchronised with the "default" one? Or is it the same storage and I'm just initialising it wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I am also using RestKit in my application. To manage/store application data other than RestKit data I implemented reverse approach of what you have tried. I configured the restKit first and used that context for other data.

I have created a RestKitHandler class to manage all restKit based activities and I am using the singleton - `[RestKitHandler sharedInstance]` instance of that class in all other part of application.

Create a strong property of `RKObjectManager` in you `RestKitHandler` class,

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) RKObjectManager *objectManager;
```

And in your `RestKitHandler.m` configure restKit like,

```
// Configure RestKit
NSString *const baseURL = @"http://baseURL";

self.objectManager = [RKObjectManager managerWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:baseURL]];
[_objectManager.HTTPClient setDefaultHeader:@"KEY" value:@"value"];
_objectManager.requestSerializationMIMEType = RKMIMETypeJSON;

[[AFNetworkActivityIndicatorManager sharedManager] setEnabled:YES];

// Set up persistance storage and create managed object context to connect RestKit with CoreData
NSManagedObjectModel *managedObjectModel = [NSManagedObjectModel mergedModelFromBundles:nil];
RKManagedObjectStore *managedObjectStore = [[RKManagedObjectStore alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:managedObjectModel];
_objectManager.managedObjectStore = managedObjectStore;

[managedObjectStore createPersistentStoreCoordinator];

NSString *storePath = [RKApplicationDataDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"YourApp.sqlite"];

NSError *error;

NSPersistentStore *persistentStore = [managedObjectStore addSQLitePersistentStoreAtPath:storePath fromSeedDatabaseAtPath:nil withConfiguration:nil options:@{NSMigratePersistentStoresAutomaticallyOption:@YES, NSInferMappingModelAutomaticallyOption:@YES} error:&error];

NSAssert(persistentStore, @"Failed to add persistent store with error: %@", error);

[managedObjectStore createManagedObjectContexts];

// Configure a managed object cache to ensure we do not create duplicate objects
managedObjectStore.managedObjectCache = [[RKInMemoryManagedObjectCache alloc] initWithManagedObjectContext:managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];
```

Through this method you can get all core data related objects from the `objectManager` instance like,

```
[[[[RestKitHandler sharedInstance] objectManager] managedObjectStore] persistentStoreManagedObjectContext];

OR

[[[[RestKitHandler sharedInstance] objectManager] managedObjectStore] mainQueueManagedObjectContext];

// Also all other objects like this
```